# Find the closed formula for $\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} \cdot b^i$

Tags: summation, closed-form

For $a, b, n \in \mathbb N^0$, find the closed formula for the sum of the following sequence:
$$(a^{n} \cdot b^0),(a^{n-1} \cdot b^1),(a^{n-2} \cdot b^2) \ldots (a^2 \cdot b^{n-2}),(a^1 \cdot b^{n-1}),(a^0 \cdot b^n)$$ 
i.e.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} \cdot b^i.$$

Also, does this sum have a special name?

Comment: Factor out $a^n$ and group $(b/a)^i$. You now have a geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: What do you get when you multiply this sum by $a-b$ ?

Comment: This should have been obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Divide the summation by $a^n$. The result should be much more familiar...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} \cdot b^i=\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$$